# Select option validation

Tags: html

Is this HTML valid?

```
<select>    
    <option value="3" />Business Analysis </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: yes its valid, what is your question ?  this most edit to<option value="3" >                this   /> use when you want close tag

Comment: It is not valid because option tag was already closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,This is valid and working syntax. Suggestion is to use `<option value="3">` instead of `<option value="3" />`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct except the option tag is closed in the open tag due to the / at the end of it.

W3schools a great resource for everything HTML related and a lot more.  [Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) a link to their page on the select tag.  If you can't find a tag in the index on their pages, you can google "w3schools tagname" and the page you're looking for will be in the first results almost, if not every time.